# I want to replace text in component "x" by clicking a button from component "y"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, button

I got two components that i want to connect. In component "x" i got some text in the template file and in component "y" i got a button that i want to click to replace/change the text in component "x".

this is "x" text i want to change:

`<p> Text i want to replace </p>`

this is "y" component.ts text i want to replace with:

```
  changeTheText: string = "Text i want to change to";
  showMyContainer2: boolean = false;

  clearMe(){
    this.showMyContainer2 = true;
    this.UIS.clearStorage();
  }
```

this is "y" component.template:

```
<button id="clearBtn" (click)="clearMe()">Change the text button</button>
<div *ngIf="showMyContainer2">
{{changeTheText}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `EventEmitters`

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 0):

Is `x` a direct child of `y`? Meaning is the HTML like this?

```
<y>
  <x></x>
</y>
```

If so, you can use `@Input()` properties

In `x` component.ts, do this:

```
// import Output and EventEmitter from '@angular/core`;
@Input text: string;
```

And I assume the HTML is:

```
<p>{{ text }}</p>
```

Then in `y.component.ts`, do:

```
clearMe(){
    this.showMyContainer2 = true;
    this.UIS.clearStorage();
    this.changeTheText = 'New Text you want'
  }
```

And in `y`.html, do:

```
<div class="y">
  <x [text]="changeTheText"></x>
</div>
```

You can possibly use `EventEmitters` like Mamosek mentioned but it depends on the heirarchy of `x and y`. Are they parent => child or child => parent.

If they don't have parent child relationship, you have to create a middle man `Service` that has a `BehaviorSubject` and both `x` and `y` have to inject this `Service` and communicate through that `BehaviorSubject` by doing `.next` to push a new value and `.subscribe` to listen to values.

====================== Edit ================================

Does it make sense for the text to live in component Z?

Component Z.ts

```
textToChange = 'Change this text';

changeTheText() {
  this.textToChange = 'new text';
}
```

Component Z.html

```
<div class="z">
  // feed the text down to the x component
  <x [text]="textToChange"></x>
  // listen to the textChanged event from component Y and every time it happens call the function changeTheText
  <y (textChanged)="changeTheText()"></y>
</div>
```

Component X.ts

```
// take input of text from parent's location
@Input() text: string;
```

Component X.html

```
<div>{{ text }}</div>
```

Component Y.ts

```
@Output textChanged: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

changeTheText() {
  // emit the event so the text can change in component Z
  this.textChanged.emit();
}
```

Component Y.html

```
<button (click)="changeTheText()">Change the text</button>
```

I freestyled all of that so there might be some errors but you get the idea.

If the text cannot live in component Z, you will have to have a centralized approach like I mentioned before this edit.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TextChangeService {
  text = new BehaviorSubject('initial value of text');
  constructor() { }

}
```

component X.ts (The HTML's for both components remain the same)

```
text: string;
constructor(textService: TextService){ }

ngOnInit() {
  this.text.subscribe(text => this.text = text);
}
```

component Y.ts

```
constructor(textService: TextService){ }

changeTheText() {
  this.textService.next('New text');
}
```

This last approach I showed you, I don't recommend because it turns into convoluted code the more you build on it. I suggest you learn the Redux pattern and use NGRX.

Comment: both "x" and "y" is in the same heirarchy, they both are under lets say "z".